# How to delete rows from google spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets

### How to delete rows from google spreadsheet

I am working on google spreadsheet with node.js, I'm able to read, write, update spread sheet, but need a code for deleting particular row.

```
sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
    auth: auth,
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    range: sWorkSheet + '!A2:B', //Change Sheet1 if your worksheet's name is something else
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    resource: {
      values: aSpreadSheetData
    }
  }, (err, response) => {
```

Comment: Please mention the npm module name

Comment: i ma not sure if update is the method youa re looking for https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#delete_rows_or_columns
the example seems to be using batchupdate?

Comment: Can I ask you about the delete you want? Do you want to delete the rows? or Do you want to delete values in the rows?

Comment: I want to delete complete row.

Comment: var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
npm modules

Comment: I'm sorry for late response, I posted my answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it deletes 1st row, a following script can be used. The script deletes completely a row. I used [`batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate#batch_update_operations).

In this case, a1Notation cannot be used. [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#gridrange) has to be used for this situation. If you want to delete several rows, you can do it by setting the GridRange.

#### Script :

```
sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
  auth: auth,
  spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
  resource: {
    "requests": 
    [
      {
        "deleteRange": 
        {
          "range": 
          {
            "sheetId": sheetId, // gid
            "startRowIndex": 0,
            "endRowIndex": 1
          },
          "shiftDimension": "ROWS"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}, (err, response) => {
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Mangesh Darekar Thank you, too.